# Criteria needed to send email alert in process builder based on lead source

Tags: salesforce

When a new lead is entered into salesforce with the lead source "Dedicated Office," we want to send an email alert. We are using Process Builder. Below is our current criteria condition inside of our process:

[image]

We are using the Lead object:
[image]

There are probably several ways of accomplishing this task, but we prefer to use PB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly. If you are just looking for someone to check your work, what you have here is correct logically and seemingly should fire in the manner you specified. I interpret this in natural language as "When a Lead with Lead Source equal to Dedicated Office is created, send an email one hour after." Just a couple suggestions here:

- `Lead.CreatedDate == Lead.CreatedDate` doesn't add any value to your triggering criteria. This will always evaluate as true. Consider removing this.
- Why the 1 hour delay? If you want to be notified that a new lead created, why wait an hour? If there's no business requirement for this, consider moving the email alert to the *Immediate Action* section
- If you are going to use Process Builder, try to follow the "one process builder per object rule." The company I work for institutes this policy (in flow and split between Before Save/After Save) and it WILL make your life easier for maintainability sake.
- I realize you want to do this in process builder, but I'll say it anyway, declarative automation should really be handled in Flow moving forward. It's only a matter of time before this tool is deprecated and you'll be forced to maintain it in Flow anyway. Save yourself the later hassle.